# Unknown type name 'using' in XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, namespaces, objective-c++

I have a project (MyLib) inside my main project (MainApp). When I build the MainApp, XCode gives me an error in one of the .h file of MyLib:

```
using namespace cv;
```

The error message is:

```
Unknown type name 'using'
```

If I build MyLib alone, I do not have any error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I expect that header file is included from a `.m` (Objective-C) file?

Change the extension to `.mm` (Objective-C++) and it should work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the .h file is included from a .mm file.

Comment: @poiuytrez You'll have to post the file contents then.

Comment: @poiuytrez: ALL the files that include this header file are `.mm` files?

Comment: @poiuytrez: Since you can compile the library on its own without getting that warning, all of the source files in the library that you're importing the .h file into are being compiled as Objective-C++ code.  That you're getting this error when building your whole app indicates that one of the source file in your app project is importing the .h file but is not being compiled as Objective-C++.  Search project-wide for the places you `#import` or `#include` the .h file.

Comment: @NateChandler You are right. Write an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @trojanfoe NateChandler answer was more detailled. I will accept yours and upvote him.

Comment: @poiuytrez What actually turned out to be the solution?  Was it a file naming problem or that one of your `.mm` files was misconfigured to compile as Objective-C instead of Objective-C++?

Comment: @trojanfoe One of the .m file in my project was including the .h containing the using statement.

Comment: Thanks @NateChandler. You done great job. 100 vote up from me.